# Ember-notify giving error can't read property "Service" of undefined

Tags: javascript, ember.js, notifications

I am using ember-notify [ember-notify](https://github.com/aexmachina/ember-notify) in my ember-cli project.

```
import {
  Component,
  inject
} from 'ember';
export default Component.extend({
  notify: inject.service('notify'),
  actions: {
    sayHello() {
      this.get('notify').info('Hello there!');
    }
  }
});
```

I just copied the same example code from documentation. But I am getting error 'cannot read property "service" of undefined' for line `notify: inject.service('notify'),` I've installed this addon and did a npm install as well.

Comment: Did you restart the server after installing the addon?

Comment: I don't know if `inject` is directly available as import. You can try being explicit instead, to work around the issue: `import Ember from 'ember';` and use `Ember.inject.service('notify')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do Ember.inject

```
notify: Ember.inject.service('notify')
```

Answer (score 0):

@spectras Looks like your right atleast this is still in the latest version of the ember source.

Line #28242 of http://builds.emberjs.com/release/ember.js

```
// app/controllers/application.js
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  someService: Ember.inject.service()
});
```

pointing to the fact that you should still have to do this as inject is only exported on the Ember object